# Can ERC20 Token be minted and rewarded automatically based on whatever command?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, tokens, contract-deployment, erc-20

I have a project where I intend to pay my users through a ERC20 Token.

We intent to develop an AI learning machine which will gather information from users activities based on task they need to accomplish on our platform to get paid. We want the AI software to interact with the smart contract by updating it with the information needed. Once the smart contract receives such info, then it will mint the needed token and reward each members in their ethereum wallet based on the report the AI has supplied.

I'll like to know if this is possible and how it could be done.

Your kind contribution will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: To use one single API link to generate results and based on the results mint tokens (even if you use the best trusted oracle system) defeats the purpose of a blockchain smart contract which is to make it fully trust-less and decentralized.

Answer (score 3):

## ERC balanceOf function

An account address' ERC 20 balance is simply whatever the `balanceOf` function says it is.

As you can define the function, you can decide what it says the balance is for each account.

This means that you can do all kinds of wacky things, based on however you decide the contract should operate.

There is nothing special or mystical about an ERC20 token, other than the specification for the required function names.

## "Minting" coins

For most contracts minting coins is nothing but adding a number to one variable without subtracting a number from another variable. Conversely burning coins is subtracting a number from one variable without adding it to another variable. Generally the variables that handle the balances are a mapping between the account address and the balance.

### Example

```
/// @notice Will cause a certain `_value` of coins minted for `_to`.
/// @param _to The address that will receive the coin.
/// @param _value The amount of coin they will receive.
function mint(address _to, uint _value) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner); // assuming you have a contract owner
    balances[_to] += value;
    supply += value;
    require(balances[_to] >= value && supply >= value); // overflow checks
    emit Transfer(address(0), _to, _value);
}
```

But this is not set in stone and your contract can do anything from within the `balanceOf` function that you can possibly think of.

To answer your question specifically, yes, you can have a function which only you can call that will create new tokens out of thin air based upon user actions external to the contract.

## Gas costly?

Be aware that calling the `mint()` function as defined about will cost you (or someone) gas each time you execute the function to create the new tokens.

Often to alleviate this problem, people will put in "batch" or "airdrop" functionality into the contract so that multiple updates can be done within a single call and thus save gas.

### Example:

```
/// @notice Will cause a certain `_value` of coins minted for `_to`.
/// @param _to The address that will receive the coin.
/// @param _value The amount of coin they will receive.
function mint(address _to, uint _value) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner); // assuming you have a contract owner
    mintToken(_to, _value);
}

/// @notice Will allow multiple minting within a single call to save gas.
/// @param _to_list A list of addresses to mint for.
/// @param _values The list of values for each respective `_to` address.
function airdropMinting([]address _to_list, []uint _values) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner); // assuming you have a contract owner
    require(_to_list.length == _values.length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < _to_list.length; i++) {
        mintToken(_to_list[i], _values[i]);
    }
}

/// Internal method shared by `mint()` and `airdropMinting()`.
function mintToken(address _to, uint _value) internal {
    balances[_to] += value;
    supply += value;
    require(balances[_to] >= value && supply >= value); // overflow checks
    emit Transfer(address(0), _to, _value);
}
```

In this example, you can call the airdropMinting function once a day (or whatever interval you feel is adequate) with a list of minting items and it will execute each in turn, saving about 21,000 gas per additional item.

**Note:** we have redefined mint() to call an internal minting function, and while we could have called the original `mint()` function from within `mintToken()`, the calling of an external function from internally comes with an additional gas cost.

**Note 2:** there is a limit on the number of items that you can mint at one time, and this is based off the global gas limit of 8 million gas.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer. If not let me know so I can further assist.

Comment: that is a beautiful answer actually. it sure helps me. especially about internal / external calls i did not know that.